# Linq filtering a list by a composite key (contains and not contains)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate, composite-key

I need an understanding of how to filter a list by a composite key with the conditions "contains" and "does not contain".

I have a list

```
List<Entity>();
```

where entity is a class

```
public class Entity
{
    int id;
    string docNum;
    int docVersion;
}
```

There is a similar second list. I need to get those elements of the list that match the following condition:
**"Get the elements of the first list, the document numbers of which are the same as the second, and the versions of the documents differ in the same document numbers".**

I tried to use `Contains()` in conjunction with `Select()` like:

```
firstList
    .Where(x => secondList.Select(y => y.docNum).Contains(x.docNum))
    .Where(x => !secondList.Select(y => y.docVersion).Contains(x.docVersion))
```

but I'm afraid it does not take into account the fact that I need to compare document numbers as well.

It seems to me that this should be resolved through `GroupBy()` or `ToDictionary()`, but I can't get to the solution.

Please, if possible, show an example of a solution on standard linq elements, because I use *NHibernate*

Comment: you need the elements in the first list that have the same docNumber but different version of the second list? right?

Comment: @L.Trabacchin exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do more complex comparisons using `Any()` rather than `Select().Contains()`. For instance, filtering if the composite key exists in `secondList` goes like this:

```
.Where(x => !secondList.Any(y => y.docNum == x.docNum && y.docVersion == x.docVersion)
```

This is slightly more efficient in this case than `Select().Contains()` since there's no intermediate object construction. In some cases where the intermediate object is more complex the savings go up.

I'd recommend that you use `Any()` for your first condition as well, giving you something like:

```
firstList
.Where(x => x.Any(y => y.docNum == x.docNum))
.Where(x => !secondList.Any(y => y.docNum == x.docNum && y.docVersion == x.docVersion)
```

The first `Where()` will filter out any items that don't have a matching `docNum` in the list, the second will filter the remaining items to remove those that have a full composite match on the second list.

Of course this is terribly inefficient since you have to scan `secondList` twice - partially, but still two scans. It would be better to do a lookup for version numbers keyed on document number and use that to do much more efficient filtering:

```
var lu = secondList.ToLookup(y => y.docNum, y => y.docVersion);

firstList.Where
(
    x => 
    { 
        var l = lu[x.docNum]; 
        return l.Any() && !l.Any(v => v == x.docVersion);
    }
)
```

Since `ILookup<>` is reasonably well optimized the actual time taken to do the filter is greatly reduced. Using some very simple (mostly-)random list generation with reasonably high collisions I tested filtering 10,000 items against a list of 1,000,000 items to see what the difference would be. 49 seconds for the first option, 1.8 seconds with a lookup.

That said, this is really only going to work well on `IEnumerable<>`. If you're operating on an `IQueryable<>` then stick with `Any()` and good indices.

Comment: this is exactly what i've looking for. It should be mentioned that I did not select the data in the way shown above, but used
var secondListDocNumVersion = secondList
    .Select (x => new 
    {
        x.docNum,
        x.docVersion
    });
followed by filtering through Any:
var result = firstList.Where(x => secondListDocNumVersion
    .Any(y => y.docNum == x.docNum && y.docVersion != x.docVersion))

I think using of != is better for my logic.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood what you want this should do:

```
var results = list1
    .Where(l1 => list2.Select(l2 => l2.DocNum).Contains(l1.DocNum))
    .GroupJoin(list2, l1 => l1.DocNum, l2 => l2.DocNum, (e, c) => new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<Entity>>(e.DocNum, c.Prepend(e)))
    .ToArray();
```

or

```
var results = list1
    .GroupJoin(list2, l1 => l1.DocNum, l2 => l2.DocNum, (e, c) => new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<Entity>>(e.DocNum, c.Prepend(e)))
    .Where(x => x.Value.Count() > 1)
    .ToArray();
```

Then you can further select to get the entities you need from the resulting groups, maybe to get the one with the biggest version, or all of them...

Unfortunately I've never used *NHibernate* so I'm not really sure if this is supported, maybe you'll need to first select the two lists from the database, enumerate them, and then do this on the software side...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement this might be easier to do using the LINQ Query syntax, the way you did and the solution I am posting are still LINQ just different ways of doing it.

```
List<Entity> firstList = new List<Entity>
        {
            new Entity
            {
                id = 1,
                docNum = "two",
                docVersion = 3
            },
             new Entity
            {
                id = 2,
                docNum = "four",
                docVersion = 4
            },
              new Entity
            {
                id = 3,
                docNum = "ten",
                docVersion = 6
            }
        };
        List<Entity> ListTwo = new List<Entity>
        {
            new Entity
            {
                id = 1,
                docNum = "two",
                docVersion = 5
            },
             new Entity
            {
                id = 2,
                docNum = "eight",
                docVersion = 7
            },
              new Entity
            {
                id = 3,
                docNum = "ten",
                docVersion = 5
            }
        };
        var resultList = from list in firstList
                         from list2 in ListTwo
                         where list.docNum == list2.docNum
                         where list.docVersion != list2.docVersion
                         select list;
```

1. First, we created the two lists on which our resulting list will be created from. These are `firstList` and `ListTwo`
2. Then declared a `var` and assigned to it the result of our LINQ query
3. `from list in firstList from list2 in ListTwo` is used to select our two data stores, and we give a name to refer to the individual element in those data stores `list` and `list2`
4. `where list.docNum == list2.docNum where list.docVersion != list2.docVersion` is used to satisfy our conditions. The first where clause checks to see if the `docNum` in `list` and `list2` match. Then, the second where clause checks to make sure that the `docVersion` in `list1` and `list2``` are not equal.
5. `select list` is used to select the item that matches our where clauses. EDIT *if you need the Entity that matched from both sources* change `select list` to `select new {list,list2}`

If you were to debug this code, you will see that`resultList` has two values (see image).
[image]

Comment: Now what happens when you have 5 versions of the same document in `secondList`, including one that has the same `docNum` and `docVersion` as one of the rows in `firstList`? What is your output compared to his pair of `Where()` statements?